# Failing when tested with 90 test cases

Tags: python

I am making a simple program to check if a UID is valid or not:

- It must contain at 2 least uppercase English alphabet characters.
- It must contain at 3 least digits (0-9).
- It should only contain alphanumeric characters (a-z, A-Z & 0-9).
- No character should repeat.
- There must be exactly 10 characters in a valid UID.

This is the code I'm using:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    values = [str(input()) for q in range(1,n+1)]

def checker():
    cap_count = 0
    num_count = 0
    alnm_count = 0
    
    for x in values[:]:
        for p in x:
            if p.isupper():
                cap_count = cap_count+1
            if cap_count > 1 and p.isnumeric():
                num_count = num_count+1
        if (len(x) == 10) and (x.isalnum()) and (len(x) == len(set(x))) and (cap_count > 1) and (num_count > 2):
            print("Valid")
        else:
            print("Invalid")
            
checker()
```

Sample Input:

```
2  
B1CD102354  
B1CDEF2354
```

So, on giving these inputs, it works well. I have tried it up to 6-7 inputs and it works.

There is no error, it's just not giving the answer on one test case with 90 values.
[Here is a link to the test that I am attempting](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/validating-uid/problem?isFullScreen=true&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen)

Comment: Test it with 123ABCDEFG.

Comment: Should say valid but it says invalid

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe for the edit and not flagging it.

Comment: So you have just ONE test case which consists of just TEN characters. If you get a pencil and a piece of paper I'm sure you'll be able to track the execution of your code on this specific test (as I did, even without that test case) and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: @ciapan thanks for noticing my naive mistake. Found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason that the numeric test is dependent on the uppercase test.

Change:

```
if cap_count > 1 and p.isnumeric():
```

to:

```
if p.isnumeric():
```

Also, the counters should be reset for every new value, so move the counter initialization inside the loop:

```
for x in values[:]:
    cap_count = 0
    num_count = 0
    ...
```

Comment: No, it's just to ensure that before checking for the number of numeric items there are enough uppercase items as to not run the whole code if the 1st condition is not satisfied.
Though I did what you asked and it didn't make much effect

Comment: But that's the problem. There should be no order to those conditions. All conditions have to be satisfied, and that's done with the `and` operator in the condition `if (len(x) == 10) and (x.isalnum()) and (len(x) == len(set(x))) and (cap_count > 1) and (num_count > 2):`. `cap_count` and `num_count` are simple counters so the conditions for `cap_count = cap_count+1` and `num_count = num_count+1` should be independent of each other.

Comment: That's true, I was putting an extra line for nothing, thanks for bringing that to my notice. But it still doesn't work in the case I am talking about. I am still failing on that test case.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the [Hackerrank problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/validating-uid/copy-from/87080995)

Following code for conditions works.

```
def checker(uid):
    if len(uid) != 10: return False
    if not uid.isalnum(): return False
    if len(uid) != len(set(uid)): return False
    if len([c for c in uid if c.isdigit()]) < 3: return False
    if len([c for c in uid if c.isupper()]) < 2: return False
    
    return True
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    for _ in range(n):
        if checker(input()):
            print("Valid")
        else:
            print("Invalid")
```

Answer (score 0):

The second condition seems to accept digits only if at least two upper case letters were found before. In other words, digits appearing before the second upper case letter are not counted.  It's due to the `cap_count > 1` term in the condition.

In the example `"123ABCDEFG"` from my comment above, all digits appear before all letters, so the digit counter remains zero and the final test `(num_count > 2)` fails.

Answer (score 0):

This is the offending line:

```
if cap_count > 1 and p.isnumeric():
```

which is actually adding an unwanted constraint, i.e. making digits acceptable only if at least 2 capitals were found.

By the way, this is the sort of data validation that `regex` is designed for, meaning that you can do all those checks in a couple of lines:

```
import re
pattern = r"^(?=(?:[a-z\d]*[A-Z]){2})(?=(?:\D*\d){3})(?:([a-zA-Z\d])(?!.*\1)){10}$"
regex = re.compile(pattern)
if regex.match("uid_here"):
    do_something
```

I strongly suggest you delve into `re` documentation (especially the *howto* section) if you're willing to dissect that weird pattern and know exactly what it does.

But for the sake of summarizing a *TL;DR*, each element of the pattern defines a specific rule that the string must comply with to match the pattern, i.e:

`^` and `$` represent the ends of the string

`(?=(?:[a-z\d]*[A-Z]){2})` this makes sure that at least 2 capitals are found

`(?=(?:\D*\d){3})` this makes sure that at least 3 digits are found

`(?:([a-zA-Z\d])(?!.*\1)){10}` this makes sure that the string has exactly 10 characters with no repetition allowed